# Accuracy low if test data belong to a single class

Tags: classification, random-forest

For my classification task I have two classes labeled 0 and 1. 
I am using Random Forests from sklearn package in python.

I have two files for different classes. So I loaded the files, combined them into one data array and trained my classifier. When I perform k fold cross validation on my input data my classifier scores at the around 98%

However, when I test the classifier on another piece of data which belongs to only one of the classes, my accuracy drops down to around 50%

Whats even more weird is that when I take two different data arrays for each class combine them. I get accuracy of around 90% with my classifier.

What's happening here? I'm confused

Note :-

Class Distribution for my training data is around 55 - 45 percent

Comment: It's hard to say. Can you say more about your data, etc? Is this an unbalanced classes issue?

Comment: Classes are almost equally distributed

Comment: some part of the procedure is a bit unclear: "classifier" can refer to a class of classifciation algorithms or a specific instance with estimated parameters. Based on the second use, cross-validation (what was your k?) involves a different classifier in each run, which again differs from the classifier you estimate for the ful data set. Wjhat I would do here: check sensitivity and specificity to see, wheterhyour classifier is biased in a systematic way. Hw does the data you refer to as "another piece of data" to the original data set?

Comment: @jan Classifier refers to a specific instance of a classifier with estimated parameters. I have set k = 10. 
Data I am testing on isn't part of the original dataset. 
Thanks